# How can i make my variable defined?

Tags: javascript

//I keep getting a typeError a is undefined.
yet i tried to declare my a variable on top of my code but it still doesn't work.

```
  // Get input element
  let filter = document.getElementById('filter');
  // Add event listener
  filter.addEventListener('keyup', filterNames);



  function filterNames() {
    // Get value of input
    let filterValue = document.getElementById('filter').value.toUpperCase();

    // Get names ul
    let ul = document.getElementById('names');
    // Get lis from ul
    let li = ul.querySelectorAll('li.list-group-item');

    // Loop through collection-item lis
    for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

         let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        // If matched
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = '';

        } else {
            li[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: are you sure you have `a` in every `li` ?

Comment: You might have a `li` element without any `a`'s in it. Thus, getting `li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0]` undefined.

Comment: You should probably check if `a` returns a node or not before proceeding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question I tried to replicate same

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="filter" />


<ul id="names" class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item"><a>First item</a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><a>Second item</a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><a>Third item</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
// Get input element
  let filter = document.getElementById('filter');
  // Add event listener
  filter.addEventListener('keyup', filterNames);



  function filterNames() {
    // Get value of input
    let filterValue = document.getElementById('filter').value.toUpperCase();

    // Get names ul
    let ul = document.getElementById('names');
    // Get lis from ul
    let li = ul.querySelectorAll('li.list-group-item');

    // Loop through collection-item lis
    for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

         let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        // If matched
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = '';

        } else {
            li[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

}
```

if there is no  its throwing error at this line

```
let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
```

as there is no

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59fy37zw/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue is because you don't have an `a` within your every `li` and as a result of `let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];` you get  `undefined`. So you better add a check to proceed further like

```
for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

     let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    // If matched
    if (a && a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = '';

    } else {
        li[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```